SVN Server repos location finding problem
I can connect to the SVN Server installed on Ubuntu using the command line because there is no GUI. My problem is that I don't know where the repos are stored in the svn system and I couldn't find it in my search. We use Tortoise but that doesn't help me to get to where the repos are stored. I would appreciate if you can help me with this.
I have examined many definition files such as config files etc. but there is no repository available in the specified places.
My expectation is to find out where and how the repository file structure I want to find is kept.

The default seems to be below /var/svn but all the config files should point there (look for SVNPath). However, it's not clear what you want to accomplish. You'd connect to a repo using a URL and its actual storage location should not matter. It's also not clear what you want to do with a repo. It's a database format, you won't find your files there.

Hello @Friedrich . First of all, thank you for your comment.  I want to access the physical area where the files in the repository are kept on the server. I do not want to access the files with a url and make a checkout or commit operation. My goal is to access the physical area where the files are kept. Unfortunately I can't find where the files (code files and all other files) are stored on the ubuntu device.

@iborzitti what Friedrich is pointing to the fact that files the way you see them on a working copy won't be available in the repo as it is all stored not as the plain files in the FS. If you have an svn service hosted somewhere, the config files of the service should point to the location where the repo is.

Knowing how your repo is shared will guide you to the respective configuration files. See Red Bean Book, chapter Server Configuration for all the details. The server's config will contain a path to the repo. You can figure it out yourself or [edit] and share the details.

And, as said before by eftshift0 and me: there won't be any source code files there. If you want to have them, you'll need to svn checkout or svn export.

Thank you for your help and information @Friedrich and eftshift0
